# Javascript - insert placeholder values in an array to maintain array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working with Google Spreadsheets, and I'm able to return an array of arrays, where a nested array is a row in the spreadsheet.

Each row needs to be exactly the same length, but there isn't necessarily a value for every cell, so to make up for these *sparse* values, I using a placeholder called `empty`.

For example, if the filter type is EXCLUDE or INCLUDE, four values will be available (`details.field`, `details.matchType`, `details.expressionValue`, `details.caseSensitive`); however if the filter type is UPPERCASE or LOWERCASE, only one value will be available (`details.field`).

Full code is below, it looks a lot larger than it is - just lots of if statements.

Is there a better way of handling these sparse, placeholder elements? I'd like to cut down on code.

```
Api.prototype.getAccountFilterData = function (accountsList) {
    var details, rowDefaults;
    var empty = '-';
    var results = [];

    accountsList.forEach(function (account) {
        this.wrapperGetAccountFilterData(account.id, function (filtersList) {
            filtersList.forEach(function (filter) {
                rowDefaults = [
                    account.name,
                    account.id,
                    filter.name,
                    filter.id,
                    filter.type
                ];

                if (filter.type === 'EXCLUDE' || filter.type === 'INCLUDE') {
                    details = filter.getIncludeDetails() || filter.getExcludeDetails();

                    results.push(rowDefaults.concat([
                        details.field,
                        details.matchType,
                        details.expressionValue,
                        details.caseSensitive,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty
                    ]));
                }

                if (filter.type === 'UPPERCASE' || filter.type === 'LOWERCASE') {
                    details = filter.uppercaseDetails || filter.lowercaseDetails;

                    results.push(rowDefaults.concat([
                        details.field,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty
                    ]));
                }

                if (filter.type === 'SEARCH_AND_REPLACE') {
                    details = filter.searchAndReplaceDetails;

                    results.push(rowDefaults.concat([
                        details.field,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        details.searchString,
                        details.replaceString,
                        details.caseSensitive,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty
                    ]));

                }

                if (filter.type === 'ADVANCED') {
                    details = filter.advancedDetails;

                    results.push(rowDefaults.concat([
                        details.field,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        empty,
                        details.fieldA,
                        details.extractA,
                        details.fieldB,
                        details.extractB,
                        details.outputToField,
                        details.outputConstructor,
                        details.fieldARequired,
                        details.fieldBRequired,
                        details.overrideOutputField,
                        details.caseSensitive
                    ]));
                }
            });
        });
    }, this);

    return results;
};
```

Comment: Consider using an [*elision*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-initializer) for non–existent members in an array literal: `([details.field, details.matchType, details.expressionValue, details.caseSensitive, , , , , , , , , , , , ,]`. Note that each comma `,` creates one member, so `[,,]` has length 2, not 3 (though older versions of IE get that wrong for trailing elisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could build a helper function to create each array

```
function createRow(type, details) {
  var len = 10, empty = '-', arr = Array(len);
  // not sure if `empty` needed or not - simple loop here if so
  switch (type) {
    case 'CASES':
        arr[0] = details.field;
      break;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Use

```
if (filter.type === 'UPPERCASE' || filter.type === 'LOWERCASE') {
    details = filter.uppercaseDetails || filter.lowercaseDetails;
    // call helper
    var row = createRow('CASES', details);
    // concat row
    results.push(rowDefaults.concat(row));
}
if(filter.ty.......
```

Answer (score 1):

If `empty` is a string, you can `.repeat` it and `.split` it to array then push it to any array, like;

```
arr.push.apply(arr, 'empty '.repeat(times).split(' ').splice(0, times));
```

*E.g.*

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(details.field, details.matchType, details.expressionValue, details.caseSensitive);
arr.push.apply(arr, 'empty '.repeat(12).split(' ').splice(0, 12));
console.log(arr);
```

*This returns,*

> [details.field, details.matchType, details.expressionValue, details.caseSensitive, "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty", "empty"]

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```js
results.push(rowDefaults.concat([
  details.field,
  details.matchType,
  details.expressionValue,
  details.caseSensitive,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty,
  empty
]))
```

You might want to convert to:

```js
results.push(rowDefaults.concat([
  details.field,
  details.matchType,
  details.expressionValue,
  details.caseSensitive
  ],
  Array(12)
  // or you can instead use below to have an array of 12 dashes
  // '------------'.split('')
))
```